# How to change scale or srcoll down in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I struggled with problem in my programm on other PC but I found the source: when I do this action this button was lower than 100% width and heigth of the screen. If I scrolling down button clicks and all is ok.

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bs-select-item'][last()]").click()

Maybe scrolling down isn't the best way. Can somebody suggest me what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to move to element before clicking on it using ActionChains:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
selectElement= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bs-select-item'][last()]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(selectElement).click().perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

or

You can use javascript as well

```
selectElement= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bs-select-item'][last()]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", selectElement)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selectElement)
```

Comment: actionChains doesn't help me( Message: target out of bonus. For better understanding my problem: I use pc with big screen where I can see full site and on my notebook 13.3 inch I need to scroll for finding element

Comment: Have you tried java script ? If its not working then can you please provide me  your url ?

Comment: @Hush: check updated solution to scroll down with actionChains

Comment: thanks after updated all works like I wanted ^^